Hawking Radiation: Why are advanced coordinates appropriate for past null infinity and retarded coordinates appropriate for future null infinity?
I've been reading Hawking's original paper https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02345020 https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-43/issue-3/Particle-creation-by-black-holes/cmp/1103899181.full?tab=ArticleLink (PDF) trying to understand his original derivation of the hawking radiation formula.
From my understanding, hawking radiation arises due to the fact that the observer in the far past and the observer in the far future   have different definitions for the vacuum.  This is because the observer in the far past uses the "advanced time" $v = t +r_*$  to define which modes have positive frequency and the observer in the far future uses the "retarded time" $u = t-r_*$ to define the modes. So since the mode decomposition of the quantum fields look different for the two observers, the creation/annihilation operators are different and hence the definition of the vacuum is different. So the vacuum as defined by the observer in the far past looks like a state that has particles for the observer in the far future. Hawking finds that in fact the state which represents the "vacuum" for the observer in the far past will looks like the thermal spectrum of a black body at a temperature $T_H$ given by the hawking temperature, which leads to the conclusion that the particles must have been "created" by the black hole / the gravitational field. So far so good, I just am having trouble understanding a key part of the logic in the derivation, which seems pretty basic, but I can't find a good source which explains this properly:
Why is "$v$" the appropriate time to use for observations in the far past and why is "$u"$ the appropriate time to use for observations in the far future ? Is it because the coordinate system with $v$ not appropriate in that region?  I can't see anything from the definitions of $u$ and $v$ which would prevent them from being in those regions. Moreover if for example $u$ can be used for both the observer in the far past and the far future then the vacuum does have a consistent definition in the far past and far future, which leads to a contradiction that there should be no hawking radiation in that case. This suggests that there is a reason why $u$ just can't be used for observations in the far past, but I'd like to see an explanation as to why.

(By construction) To "reach" a point at future null infinity you have to follow an outgoing null ray and take its limit towards infinity. The different points at future null infinity are labelled by the distinct radial null rays that lead to them. In Schwarzschild spacetime the outgoing radial null rays are given exactly by the curves with constant $u$, $\theta$ and $\phi$. Consequently, the natural coordinates describing observers "at" future null infinity are $(u,\theta,\phi)$. Future null infinity is in some sense the hypersurface where $v\to\infty$.
The converse is true for past null infinity, ingoing light rays, and $v$.

$v$ is used to specify the past null infinity because it is convenient to do so and the same goes for $u$ and future null infinity, it has nothing to do with the validity of the result.  A spherical null wave front that has a constant value of $v=v_0$ would start on past null infinity and travel inwards to reach the center at $r=0$ and $t=v_0$.  Similarly, an outgoing spherical wave front with a constant value $u=u_0$ would start at $r=0$ at $t=u_0$ and end up at $t=u_0+c$ and $r=c$ for any value of c.
Hawking's argument is that if the initial data on past null infinity is that of a normal Minkowski vacuum, (it's a collapse solution, so no black hole has formed yet), then after the collapse the state of the quantum system is no longer that of a vacuum, hence particles have been created.  No, this result does not depend on the coordinate choice, it's merely a convenient coordinate system to use.  You could do the entire calculation in the same coordinate system $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$, specifying the quantum state to be the vacuum at some far past time $t\rightarrow-\infty$ before the black hole formed and then calculate the solution to the Klein-Gordon equation everywhere in the spacetime.  This would be very complicated to do, I don't believe it has ever been done.  For example, you could take the Oppenheimer-Snyder metric https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Snyder_model, which represents a collapsing dustball, and solve the Klein-Gordon equation on it in a single set of coordinates, you should get Hawking radation.
